# What is the appropriate way to import and use moment.js for use in a browser?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment.js within the browser for easier date/time formatting, but I get an uncaught syntax error... I'm importing outside of a module, apparently, and that's a no-no? Here's the full error in Chrome Developer Tools:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Here's my very simple .js file as it stands now:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

// Reset button functionality
function startOver() {
    const confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you would like to clear the form and start over? " +
        "Press OK to start over. Press cancel to return.");
    if (confirmation) { $('#NetProceedsCalculator').trigger("reset"); }
}

jQuery(function() {
    $('#reset').on("click", function () { startOver() });
    // Information is added to the form
    $('.recalc').on("change", function () {
        let closing_date = $('#est_closing_date').val();
    });
});
```

I really don't understand the JavaScript universe, as this is literally my first day coding in it. I don't know if I'm using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) (I don't think so?). I am using [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). My JavaScript language version, according to [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm), is [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)+... I suppose that means I'm not using Node.js?

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to correctly import Moment.js for use within a browser. I'd also appreciate guidance on how to navigate the very confusing (to me) world of JavaScript—beginner's guides and all that. I do have experience with programming, but I've always strayed away from JavaScript because it was just so damn... intimidating to me, lol.

---

I have added a CDNJS link to Moment.js within my HTML file, and I can verify that it is appropriately linked as follows:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the date you want to format with moment JS. Can you please provide a minimal working example of your above or a `[<>]` snippet

Comment: You can check https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js to know what you have to import for your case with locale. In your case, as you don't use modules, import moment in script tag is your way to have it.
You can have a look at https://momentjs.com/ too for starting or  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ for more complex operation

Comment: @JB_DELR this worked! Simply taking out my import statement solved the issue. I feel dumb. Can you give me a brief rundown of what a module is in JS / link me to a good explanation?

Comment: Sorry, but it's allways a little bit abstract for me for the moment. I just know how, when and where to use them. Module are dependencies. If you want to start with them, maybe have a look at Require.js